# Image overflow by body

Tags: css, height, overflow

I want to cut image when body height < img height.

Here jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/AKsaS/

I need all height (1200+px).

```
img{
height: 100%; /* bad */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url('http://oboshto.ru/upme/shits/left%20%281%29.png');
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

SOME CONTENT

    <div id="cut"> < - -CUT CUT CUT </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AKsaS/3/

You could also place a `position: relative` on #wrapper, which would cut it off to the wrapper as well.  JsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/AKsaS/4/